# Firefox vs. Chrome CSS lining up issue

Tags: css, cross-browser, ubuntu-11.10

*(see attached jsfiddle, screenshots; running browsers on Ubuntu 11.10)*

There seems to be some kind of a lining up issue when I try to put divs into other divs. I don't know how exactly to explain, so please see below screenshot & you can also check out my jsfiddle as well.

screenshot (left is firefox, right is chrome):
[image]

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kWLbS/1/

I just want the div with the gold background to fit nicely inside of the toolbar, that is all! No idea why I keep running into this "off by one pixel" issue between the two browsers. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Im using the latest firefox version and I don't see it like you do.
What version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me in firefox as well, but try http://jsfiddle.net/a5vJC/

I suspect the real issue is the difference in fonts. They look similar but have subtle differences. I think if you set the font manually that might also fix the issue though that's not what I did.